# Chip programmatically generated not responding to click in ChipGroup

Tags: java, android

I've made a chipgroup and I want to dynamically generate in java its content, populating it with filter chips made from strings. I've made the Chipgroup but trying to add chips I notice that, no matter what I do, the chips are not responding to clicks. I also tried to make a single chip in the design editor and moving it in the same chipgroup, the results is that the design editor created chip is working as intended (checking and unchecking it), the generated ones are static (in the same group).

the code I use for the single working one:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
     android:id="@+id/iChipGroup"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:chipSpacing="8dp"
     app:singleSelection="true" >

     <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
         android:id="@+id/chip2"
         style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="cwae" />
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

the way I create the dynamic ones

```
Chip chip = new Chip(iChipGroup.getContext());
ChipDrawable chipDrawable = ChipDrawable.createFromAttributes(getContext(), null, 0, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Chip_Filter);
chip.setChipDrawable(chipDrawable);
chip.setText(myText);
iChipGroup.addView(chip);
```

I've also tried to set an `OnCheckedhangeListener` both on the single chips and `ChipGroup`, got nothing.
If it helps, my hierarchy is (inside a fragment):

```
frameLayout
-scrollView
--LinearLayout
---chipGroup
----chip...
```

Answer (score 0):

managed to make the chip respond by changing the way I made them this way

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
Chip chip = (Chip)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_filter_chip,ingredientsChipGroup, false);
```